# angularjs - counting in reverse in ng-repeat with filtering

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an array of 115 books stored in details below in ng-repeat. When using {{$index +1}} a count of 1 to 115 appears. If I filter the books by last name and show 12, {{$index + 1}} will show a count of 1 to 12. Is it possible to instead show a reverse count using $index so that the count starts with the highest number and goes to lowest? Without filtering, this will work using {{details.length - $index}} but when filtering the results in 12 items show 115 through 104 instead of 12 through 1.

I have an ng-repeat like this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="det in details | orderBy:['-YEAR_READ','-UniqueCounter'] | filter:searchingFor>
    <td>{{$index + 1}}</td>
    <td>{{details.length - $index}}</td>
    <td>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently while showing the index you are referring the unfiltered collection, therefore you can't see the filtered result count using `details.length` variable. Use alias filter object using `as` would do the trick like `ng-repeat="item in item | filter: { prop: 'search' }| customFilter as filteredResult"`

```
<tr 
  ng-repeat="det in details | orderBy:['-YEAR_READ','-UniqueCounter'] | filter:searchingFor as filtered">
    <td>{{$index + 1}}</td>
    <td>{{filtered.length - $index}}</td>
    <td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can apply to the collection a new filter to get the reverse behavior, like:

```
app.filter('reverse', function() {
  return function(items) {
    return items.slice().reverse();
  };
});
```

and use it like:

```
<tr ng-repeat="det in details |reverse | orderBy:['-YEAR_READ','-UniqueCounter'] | filter:searchingFor >
    <td>{{$index + 1}}</td>
    <td>{{details.length - $index}}</td>
    <td>
</tr>
```

Comment: will display length of unfiltered array